# in iPad screen it is not displaying split view

Tags: ios, ipad, swift3, uisplitview

In this split view was not displaying on the iPad screen if I drag it was displaying and if I select an index it is not displaying on the label

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let names = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        cell.isSelected = true
        cell.textLabel?.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    // MARK:- Storyboard segue

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "ShowDetailIdentifier") {
            var detail: DetailsViewController
            if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController {
                detail = navigationController.topViewController as! DetailsViewController
            } else {
                detail = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
            }

            if let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                detail.selectedIndex = path.row + 1
            }
        }
    }
```

the code in master view controller

```
  @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
        var selectedIndex:Int = 1

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            numberLabel?.text = "\(selectedIndex)"
            print(selectedIndex)

            if splitViewController?.responds(to: #selector(getter: UISplitViewController.displayModeButtonItem)) == true {
                navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
```

the code in details view controller

```
class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController,UISplitViewControllerDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        splitViewController?.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryOverlay
        splitViewController?.delegate = self
                     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController,
                             collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController,
                             onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

the code for split view controller

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this`a`tableView.reloadData()`on your`viewDidLoad`or`viewDidAppear

Comment: table view is displaying but the problem was in iPad layout the value which I was selected was not passing to the details view controller

Comment: Have you checked if you are you setting the label's text property before viewDidLoad?

Comment: are u having any one of the split view controller project done previously ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing `if let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` at the end of your prepareForSegue. Do you have the segue connected from your tableViewCell to your destinationVC?

Comment: yes to send the selected index to display on the details view controller

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where are you initializing the splitviewcontroller you need to pass the TableViewController, and detailViewController. 
You need to pass it in the viewDidLoad of the class inheriting form UISplitViewController

```
self.viewControllers = [masterNav, detail]
```

and to always show splitviewcontroller you need this

```
self.displayMode = .allVisible
```

Comment: later on I changed and added now problem is when I run the app on iPad it is not passing value from master to details and when I rotate to landscape it is not working completely when I rotate it later it was working fine and passing all the values

Comment: it was passing the value when I rotate two times the iPad screen

Comment: i cannot see your didSelectIndexPath method.

Comment: see in my master view controller                                                                           if let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                detail.selectedIndex = path.row + 1
            }

Comment: if possible can you please send me ur mail id so that u can check and tell me what's wrong in my project ?